# Press any key to continue

Tags: powershell

According to Microsoft's [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176935.aspx), `read-host` lets the user type some input, and then press enter to continue. Not exactly the correct behavior if you want to have "Press any key to continue". (Wait... where's the <kbd>Any</kbd> key?!)

Is there a way to accomplish this? Something like `read-char`?

I've tried searching for "single character input" and "powershell input" to see if I could find a list of all ways to get input without much luck. And several Stack Overflow questions that looked hopeful use `read-host` which doesn't *actually* work for "press any key..." functionality.

Comment: Nice old [powershell tip of the week](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730938.aspx) (found by searching for Powershell and Pause, pause being the command in command prompt/MS dos that showed that text)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Here is what I use.

```
Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
```

Comment: I get an error: 
```Exception calling "ReadKey" with "1" argument(s): "The method or operation is not implemented."
At C:\file.ps1:26 char:5
+     $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotImplementedException```

Comment: @gakera This does not work under Powershell ISE.

Comment: Please check out the answer from (Jerry G) for how to fix on ISE. These problems are what led me to this question

Comment: It works properly when running the script from the PowerShell command.

Answer (score 62):

I've created a little Powershell function to emulate MSDOS `pause`.  This handles whether running Powershell ISE or non ISE.  (`ReadKey` does *not* work in powershell ISE).  When running Powershell ISE, this function opens a Windows `MessageBox`.  This can sometimes be confusing, because the `MessageBox` does not always come to the forefront.  Anyway, here it goes:

Usage:
`pause "Press any key to continue"`

Function definition:

```
Function pause ($message)
{
    # Check if running Powershell ISE
    if ($psISE)
    {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$message")
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$message" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $x = $host.ui.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work in VSCode

Comment: $message ="Press any key to continue"

pause ($message)     for me it is working in ise and powershell , I have add just this lines , maybe you need to do the same in vs code ?! @ZaxLofful

Answer (score 37):

Check out the `ReadKey()` method on the `System.Console` .NET class. I think that will do what you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

```
Write-Host -Object ('The key that was pressed was: {0}' -f [System.Console]::ReadKey().Key.ToString());
```

Comment: This only works in powershell.exe - it won't work on graphical hosts like the ISE.

Comment: Up-vote for nice and simple.

Comment: Note that this only works in Powershell console, not the Powershell IDE.