# Exit from while loop but keep shell open: powershell

Tags: powershell, while-loop, exit, break

For learnig Powershell I've wrote a script that choose a film randomly from a list, until the list runs out, but, at the end of list I want that the shell keeps open... I've tried many options `Break/Return/exit`... nothing to do... tried to add the last `if` condition in to the `while` condition but, not works, at the end of list an error message says that the array is empty/null, or shell quits after last film...

Yes, I can put a `pause` instead of `return`, for that script would be ok, but it doesn't seems an "elegant" solution...

The icing on the cake would be a better option to trim the extension from film name..! Because in my mode, a film name that finish with a `"m"`, `"k"`, or `"v"`, these chars are trimmed out toghether with the `".mkv"` expression! :)

Can someone drive me please?

This is the code:

```
$LastFile = (Get-Item "F:\DATA\Films list\*" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "Title"} | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1).FullName
$TitleList = Get-Content $LastFile | where { $_ -notmatch "4K" }
$TitleList.Count

$Listed = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Foreach ( $film in $TitleList ) {
    $Listed.Add("$film") | out-null
    }
$RandomFilm = Get-Random -InputObject $Listed
Write-Host $RandomFilm.Trim('.mkv') -ForegroundColor Green
$Listed.Remove("$RandomFilm") 
$TitleCount = 1

echo "_________________________________________________________________________________________"
echo "`n`n" 
$Answer = Read-Host "RETURN for new film, q for quitting..." 

while ( "q" -notcontains $Answer) {
    echo "`n`n"
    $RandomFilm = Get-Random -InputObject $Listed 
    if ( $RandomFilm -ne $null ) {
        Write-Host $RandomFilm.Trim('.mkv') -ForegroundColor Green
        $Listed.Remove("$RandomFilm")
        $TitleCount++
        $TitleCount
        if ( $TitleCount -gt $TitleList.Count ) {
            Write-Host "END OF LIST..." -ForegroundColor red
            Return
            }
        else {
            echo "_________________________________________________________________________________________"
            echo "`n`n"
            $Answer = Read-Host "RETURN for new film, q for quitting..."
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways of doing this. If you are running your script with powershell then `$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")`at the end of the script is a good option (this will not work with powershell_ise tho). In ISE you can add a read-host at the end.
If you are running your script from a shortcut you can add `-NoExit`: powershell.exe -NoExit -file .\script.ps1

> The icing on the cake would be a better option to trim the extension from film name..! Because in my mode, a film name that finish with a "m", "k", or "v", these chars are trimmed out toghether with the ".mkv" expression! :)

Im not quite sure I understood this part, could you please elaborate.

Comment: `if ( $RandomFilm.EndWith(".mkv") { $RandomFile = $RandomFile.Remove($RandomFile.Length-4) }`

Comment: @santisq, Hi santis, tried `$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")`, seems not works, shell still quitting...

About the "icing..", I mean that "The Mask.mkv" is trimmed like this "The Mas"   !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886243/press-any-key-to-continue check this link.
Regarding the trimming question, if all files are ".mkv" you can use `'The Mask.mkv' -replace '.mkv'` or `'The Mask.mkv'.replace('.mkv','')` or `'The Mask.mkv'.split('.')[0]`

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thanks Tim, perfect! Just for who "copy and paste" will be:
`$Random**Film**.Remove($Random**Film**.Length-4)`
:)

Comment: @santisq, Yes santis, as I sayd `pause` is a solution, but I prefer to learn another/better/correct techique!

Comment: There are plenty of references to your question on the link I pasted as well as on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963100/how-do-you-do-a-pause-with-powershell-2-0 please read.

Comment: @santisq, I've read it, I swear!! But all that methods inserts a "pause" or an answer...
I think there must be a way to exit from a while loop and keep shell active... but, of course, I can be wrong!

Comment: if you want the shell still active after the loop finishes then you can either create a shortcut to your script adding the `-NoExit` flag or run the script with powershell_ise. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1